# Node.js: Is creating an MD5 hash with Crypto module fully asynchronous?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, cryptography

Considering this piece of code in a Node 11 environment and using the standard crypto module, I have two questions (and just to avoid any misunderstandings: I am simply calculating an MD5 hash based on a string - no encryption, no sensitive data):

```
exports.calculateSomeHash = function(somestring, cb){
    var somehash = crypto.createHash('md5').update(somestring).digest('hex').toString();
    cb(null, somehash);   
};
```

1) Could calculateSomeHash() ever return an empty (somehash) value as the hash calculation may perhaps not be fully completed as soon as the callback is fired?

2) Is this hashing algorithm of Node's crypto module fully asynchronous and non-blocking? If not, any recommendations on what to use alternatively? What about e.g.[Hasha](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hasha)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All these methods are blocking and synchronous:

```
crypto.createHash()
hash.update()
hash.digest()
.toString()
```

So, your result will be entirely synchronous.  You don't have to use a callback at all to communicate the result.  You can just return the result directly:

```
exports.calculateSomeHash = function(somestring){
    return crypto.createHash('md5').update(somestring).digest('hex').toString();
};
```

FYI, the crypto library does have some asynchronous methods, but these are not the ones that are asynchronous.

> Could calculateSomeHash() ever return an empty (somehash) value as the hash calculation may perhaps not be fully completed as soon as the callback is fired?

No.  They're synchronous.  There's no timing related issue with them.

> Is this hashing algorithm of Node's crypto module fully asynchronous and non-blocking?

No.  This is synchronous and blocking.  Whether that matters to you perhaps depends upon the size of the data.

The built-in crypto module does not appear to have asynchronous hash options built into node.js.  Because hashing is purely CPU work, the only way to make them non-blocking and asynchronous would be to use native threads in native code, use a WorkerThread or use a child_process.  All of those options create extra overhead that is probably not usually necessary.  But, if it was really a problem for you, you could spin up a WorkerThread and then message it a string you wanted a hash of and it could message you back the hash value.

You could look at the [bcrypt module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) which has some asynchronous hashing, but it's not quite the same functionality so you'd have to see if it fit your needs.

Comment: The data to be hashed is rather small (just URLs). What bothers me is the amount of calls that may be summing up easily as this function is part of an algorithm to calculate all image paths for a website whereas I use an MD5 file name hash to distribute many file across the file system (example: https://serverfault.com/questions/95444/storing-a-million-images-in-the-filesystem). Hence, I'd like to keep this as asynchronous and non-blocking as possible. I looked at BCrypt module but it seems to lack MD5 hashing.

Comment: One more question. Does this method call remain synchronous and blocking even if I wrap and promisify it using Bluebird promises and call it externally via return calculateSomeHashAsync().then(hashresult) ... ?

Comment: @IgorP. - It will cost you more overhead to use a true asynchronous hash for a URL than the CPU time it will take to just hash a URL directly.  This should be no problem.  The only thing that wrapping it in a promise does is allow other resolved promises to interleave with your work, but it's still blocking and synchronous while doing the hash and it will still block other types of events in the event loop.  When you do all these URLs are you hashing thousands at once or hashing each one as it comes as part of a longer process?

Comment: No, I can't calculate them at once as the requests come in sequentially when loading a website. Think of it as many <img src="loadthumbnail/someContentID" /> elements on a website.  The path of each image will then be calculated based on the provided ID. MD5 Hashing is part of that process but, as I said, I can't calculate all hashes of a webpage at once, as I don't know in advance which elements will be on a webpage.

Comment: @IgorP. - Then it's perfectly fine to be doing one at a time synchronously mixed in with other processing.  You won't notice that at all.  Calculating the hash of a URL is really, really fast.

Comment: Ok, I'll stick to it then. Thanks.